# Generate interface(s) for JSON

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to use `TypeScript` to analyze a JSON object and output an interface.

What I'm trying to do **dynamically** is to convert JSON like this:

```
{
  "foo": "some string value",
  "bar": 5,
  "baz": {
    "a": "string"
  },
  "baz2": {
    "a": "string"
  }
}
```

Call a function like this that may or may not exist:

```
typescript.doSomeMagic(objFromAbove);
// or
typescript.doSomeMagic(JSON.stringify(objFromAbove));
```

And have it output an interface (or interfaces):

```
interface IProvidedName {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: { a: string; b: number; }
  baz2: IBaz2;
}
interface IBaz2 {
  a: string;
}
```

I'm ok with either the format for `baz` or for `baz2` above.

I'm currently digging through the typescript module looking for the object inference functions.

Comment: I am curios to know why you want to do this ?

Comment: I want to be able to define the types of objects that are pulled into my application via AJAX calls. I have the JSON results of those calls and don't want to manually convert JSON to interface for each of my payloads.

Comment: Isn't `tsc --declaration` good enough?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm currently digging through the typescript module looking for the object inference functions.

There is a tool json2dts : http://xperiments.in/json2dts/

Its also integrated into atom-typescript : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/pull/466

Comment: This certainly gets the ball rolling, but would like to see improvement in the area of arrays. `{foo: [{prop1: ''}, {prop1: '', prop2: ''}]}` => `foo: {prop1: string; prop2?: string}[]` would be ideal